# PyInstaller fails on Windows 7: "Can't find a usable init.tcl"

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, windows-7, pyinstaller

I have a basic Python script which uses Tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
Tk().withdraw()
print askdirectory()
```

After compiling my script with PyInstaller, I tried to run my program on Windows 7 (64-bit) computer which didn't have Python installed.

It raised this error:

```
Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: [list of directories]
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly
```

Why does my script fail to find `init.tcl` after compiling with PyInstaller?

Comment: I faced a similar problem when copying the program to Windows 7 x64 and totally puzzled by it. Copying to Win 8 and 10 computers works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with PyInstaller and Tkinter on Windows 7 64-bit machines. There is an [issue report](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1957) in the GitHub repository of PyInstaller.

All the way at the bottom this issue was referenced from another issue, namely [this one](https://github.com/zbears/pyvona/issues/34) which says that downgrading to PyInstaller 3.1.0 helps other people solve the issue.

```
pip install pyinstaller==3.1.0
```

I myself have been able to confirm this using a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Since this has gone unfixed for nearly two years, [I've opened a bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/33205944-tkinter-fails-due-to-path-issues) for the issue on Bountysource.

Answer (score 1):

[As RedPhantom mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469243/3357935), PyInstaller has [a known issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1957) with Tkinter applications on Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Since this issue has gone unfixed for two years, I've gone ahead and [started a bounty on Bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/33205944-tkinter-fails-due-to-path-issues). Until the issue is fixed, there are a few workarounds you can try:

## Workaround 1 - Manually copy missing files

As mentioned in [a related issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1948), you can manually copy the missing files from your local Python installation.

1. Find your local Python installation. (`%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python`)
2. Make a copy of the missing folder (`...\Python36-32\tcl\<missing_folder>`)
3. Move the copy to your application's `tcl` folder (`...\dist\<app_name>\tcl\<missing_folder>`)

## Workaround 2 - Run with `--onefile`

Running PyInstaller in `--onefile` mode seems to avoid this issue.

However, note that running in single file mode will increase startup time.

## Workaround 3 - Downgrade to PyInstaller 3.1.0

```
pip install pyinstaller==3.1.0
```

[According to ugoertz](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1957#issuecomment-257579513), downgrading to PyInstaller 3.1.0 resolved the issue.

> Downgrading to 3.1.0 (and also downgrading setuptools to 19.2 because of the problem described in [#1941](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1941)) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will find that there is Tcl8.X folder in python directory, it is at a place which is not mentioned in [list of directories], you mentioned in your question. Just pick any of the paths from those directory listings (preferably /lib ).

That will allow python to find Tcl library files and it will work.

Note: DO NOT MOVE FILES, JUST COPY THEM.