# Tkinter python script converted to exe using pyinstaller on Windows 10 not working on Windows7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have recently developed a python based UI script using tkinter and python 2.7 on Windows 10 OS. To distribute it to the users I converted the script into an single file exe using pyinstaller.
The script is working fine on all Windows 10 systems but creating issue on Windows 7 as:
"Fatal Error: Can not run ... script"
I cannot wrap my head around it.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanx in advance..:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller fails on Windows 7: "Can't find a usable init.tcl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180492/pyinstaller-fails-on-windows-7-cant-find-a-usable-init-tcl)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pyinstaller` to compile your script to `executable` in `windows 10` and want to use it in `window 7` it won't work.

But you can compile it with `pyinstaller` in `windows 7` and use the executable in `windows 7, 8, and 10`

Also take note of this, take into consideration `32-bit and 64-bit` version of the operating systems when use `windows 7 32-bit` to compile your executable and want to use it in `windows 7 64-bit` operating system version it won't work and vice versa.

So when you compile in `windows7 32-bit` version it will work on only `32-bit version of operating systems` and not on `64-bit version of windows operating system` and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could try using cx_Freeze package to build your app, in windows (Note: if your PC is 64 Bits the app gonna be in that architecture and 32Bits if is x86 or 32 Bits)

run cmd and type this

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

Then make a file called setup.py ubicated in the same directory into that and add this code:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python27\\tcl\\tcl8.6" #you need to ubicate the library where tcl\tcl8.6 is
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python27\\tcl\\tk8.6" #you need to ubicate the library where tcl\tk8.6 is

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("name_of_your_app.py", base=base, icon="icon_of_your_app.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
name = "Vtext",
options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":["icon_of_your_app.ico", "maybe_some_img_that_your_app_is_using.gif", "another_img.gif"]}},
version = "1.0",
description = "name_of_your_app",
executables = executables
)"""
```

Later open a cmd and change the directory where your app is, for example:

```
C:\Users\Myname> cd C:\Users\Myname\MyTkinterApp
```

Then, type this:

```
python setup.py build
```

And is everything is ok, your app is gonna builded

Watch this video for more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HosXxXE24hA&t=0s&index=29&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk