# PyInstaller ImportError: cannot import name 'SelectorEventLoop'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-asyncio

Using PyInstaller to generate an .exe on a windows platform, i have an error when runnig the .exe:

```
> (venv) ...>my.exe Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\my.py",
> line 6, in <module>   File
> ".\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File
> "site-packages\websockets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>   File
> ".\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File
> "site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 6, in <module>   File
> ".\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 631, in exec_module exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)   File
> ".\venv\Lib\site-packages\zmq\asyncio\__init__.py", line 18, in
> <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'SelectorEventLoop' [3696]
> Failed to execute script My
```

I am using `python 3.6.4` and `pyinstaller 3.3`
I just added `ayncio 3.4.3` to the project (everything worked find before that)

Any idea would be welcomed

Comment: asyncio is part of Python 3.6. You don’t need to nor should you include the external library by the same name.

Comment: @dirn I removed it from my requirements.txt but it doens't change a thing since I do an import in my code

Comment: What @dirn wrote. asyncio 3.4.3 is a [package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/asyncio/) whose description begins with: **This version is only relevant for Python 3.3, which does not include asyncio in its stdlib.**

Comment: I’ve never used PyInstaller. Does it look at what you have installed or does it just read your requirements file? If the former, did you make sure to uninstall asyncio?

Comment: This might be related to the `websockets` lib (4.0.1) that rely on `asyncio`

Comment: Are you using Windows 7? Try running PyInstaller with `--onefile`. (Possibly related: [*PyInstaller fails on Windows 7: “Can't find a usable init.tcl”*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49902457/3357935))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot, i came up with a solution.

The sources of the issue are:

- the `zmq` (for `zeromq`) i use. It embeds its own `asyncio`
- `PyInstaller` modifies `sys.path` to add the libraries from `zeromq`.

When importing `asyncio` in my code, it tries to import the one from `zeromq`and fails.

I made an ugly hack to get around that. I post it so it might help someone

```
former_path = sys.path[:]
sys.path = [v for v in sys.path if 'zmq' not in v]
import asyncio
sys.path = former_path
```

So far, i couldn't find any side effect