# ImportError with pyinstaller compiled executable (flask, celery)

Tags: python, flask, celery, pyinstaller

I have some problems when using the executable file which is generated by pyinstaller. I try to make a stand alone tool of my script, my script is a flask + celery service that host server on localhost. The error message is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mock_server\falsk_service.py", line 14, in <module>
   File "site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
   File "site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 638, in conf
   File "site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 456, in _get_config
   File "site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
   File "site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 650, in loader
   File "site-packages\celery\loaders\__init__.py", line 25, in get_loader_cls
   File "site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
   File "site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
   File "importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module   
ImportError: No module named app
[18228] Failed to execute script falsk_service
```

My code works perfectly when run with `python flask_service.py`, but it goes wrong run with the executable. Kindly help check my code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import shutil, pickle, os, argparse, subprocess
import redis
from celery import Celery
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json, request, json, make_response
from return_messages import ReturnMessages
from background_scripts import BackgroundScripts

# initailizing
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], fixups=[])
celery.conf.update(app.config) ## Wrong in this line
```

I've searched on Internet but can't find any solution. Still not sure the root cause. I've tried using the following command to generate executable file but got same result.

```
pyinstaller --hidden_import __init__.py falsk_service.py
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7? This may be related to a similar issue [when importing tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42180492/3357935). Try running PyInstaller with `--onefile` as a potential workaround.

Comment: I am using Win10, and I've tried `--onefile` before, but it got the same result. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What versions of PyInstaller & Python are you using?